# Reading a Binary File with UTF16 format

Tags: c, binaryfiles, utf-16, utf-16le

In C language, I am trying to read a Binary file in UTF16 format.

I tried to this;

`binaryFile = fopen("data.dat", "rb, ccs=UTF16LE");`

And it did not work. I need to do this without using the UTF16 reading library specifically, and I can't think of anything other than this solution.

Can you help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove the `, ccs=UTF16LE` — unless the manual page for `fopen()` on your machine says it is supported.

Comment: I'd use libicu for working with UTF-16 encoded text, including I/O.

Comment: UTF-16 is a text encoding - so if it's in UTF-16, it's not really a "binary file" in the normal meaning of the term... it's pretty unclear what you're trying to do, at the moment.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler my machine is supporting when I write fopen("data.dat", "rb") , but it is reading the file in UTF8 format.

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry I'm new in here, I've got a binary file. I will read it and write it in a xml file. But I have to do it with UTF-16

Comment: You'll need to show a lot more code showing how you read the file and a hex dump of the first 64 bytes or so of the file (`xxd  -ug1 data.dat | sed 4q`), and then explain how you deduce that the file is read as UTF8 even though it is UTF16LE.

Comment: What do you mean by "I will read it and write it in a xml file"? Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and edit your question to be *much* clearer about what you're trying to do, the code you've got, and what's happening at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-wfopen?view=msvc-170) for `fopen`, they support a non-standard extension to specify the text encoding, but you misspelled it. It should be:

```
binaryFile = fopen("data.dat", "rb, ccs=UTF-16LE");
```

This is a typical example of the [Embrace, Extend and Extinguish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embrace,_extend,_and_extinguish) strategy deployed by this company in an attempt to lock developers in their wall garden.

Making the `ccs` flag case sensitive and using dashes are regrettable design choices. Lagging on UTF-8 adoption and encouraging 16-bit text file support is plaguing programmers to this day. Try your best to have the format of this file changed to UTF-8.